# Using regex to remove http/https and trailing slashes at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove 'http://' or 'https://' from a string if it exists, and also any trailing slashes at the end of a string.

So, with a string like 'https://yourdomain.com//////', it should return yourdomain.com.

Currently I have the following two regex patterns separately, but I don't know how to combine them.

```
url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');

url.replace(/\/+$/, '');
```

Comment: You can use an alternation `^https?:\/\/|\/+$`

Comment: Why not use the [`URL` API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL)? `new URL("https://yourdomain.com//////").host`.